# Does G-d desire relationship?

Tags: torah-study, commentaries, deveikut

From where was it derived that G-d wants to have companionship/relationship with man? On what basis has it been concluded that the Almighty seeks to have a personal relationship with man?

Someone (non-jewish person) asked me: “How do I even know G-d wants to have a relationship with me?”

Comment: Possibly related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/126479/27180

Comment: Because he told us?

Comment: Oh fun question, I'll bli neder try to answer it. Given that this is a non-Jewish person, what sort of evidence is he looking for? Would he accept a Torah source? A Rabbinic source? Or is it just logic.  One of my favourite is Hashem was "mithalech" in the garden searching for Adam. Another is the classic "I will dwell among you"

Comment: May I also recommend "God in Search of Man" by Heschel, if this is a particularly academic/philosophically minded person

Answer (score 2):

Shemos 6:7

**וְלָקַחְתִּי אֶתְכֶם לִי לְעָם וְהָיִיתִי לָכֶם לֵאלֹהִים** וִידַעְתֶּם כִּי אֲנִי יְהוָה אֱלֹהֵיכֶם הַמּוֹצִיא אֶתְכֶם מִתַּחַת סִבְלוֹת מִצְרָיִם.

**And I will take you to Me as a people, and I will be a God to you**, and you will know that I am the Lord your God, Who has brought you out from under the burdens of the Egyptians.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Torah [says](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.14.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that we are Hashem's children:

> You are the children of the L-rd your G-d

The Piaseczner Rebbe in his work (Bnei Machshava Tova) [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Bnei_Machshava_Tova%2C_The_Association%27s_Goals.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> Rather, our desire and longing is to be like a (royal) child - "you are children to Hashem your G-d" - so that in our worship of Hashem, whether in Torah, prayer or other commandments, we feel our nearness to Hashem. And like the son who rejoices to greet his father after not seeing him for several years and after suffering great longings for him, so too in our service we wish to feel our soul speeding towards its Father for whom it longs all day and night; running and dissolving - the dissolution of the soul as it spills into the embrace of its Father in heaven.

From the view of עולם האצילות, our relationship with Hashem should be viewed as like children to their father, explains the [Shelah](https://www.sefaria.org/Shenei_Luchot_HaBerit%2C_Torah_Shebikhtav%2C_Chayei_Sara%2C_Torah_Ohr.50?ven=Shney_Luchot_Habrit_by_Rabbi_Eliyahu_Munk&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

G-d is our Heavenly Father, who wants to have a relationship with His children.

Answer (score 1):

Commandments.

All commandments imply a relationship between the commander and the commanded.

All human beings are commanded by God. Jews are bound by a Torah that contains 613 Commandments, and all others only have a limited number of Commandments (the Noahide Code).

The common denominator is that God desires a relationship with ALL humans, via their acceptance of His Kingship, and their following His Commandments.